# Блокирование доступа к сайтам в роутере ZyXel

Tags: доступ, роутер

Здравствуйте!

Хотелось бы ограничить доступ к "левым" сайтам через мой роутер. Например, если существует в инете обновляющийся список сайтов не для детей, то перед тем, как выполнить запрос подключившегося к роутеру, проверить, есть ли сайт, на который он хочет перейти, в вышеуказанном списке.

Если же списка "нехороших" сайтов нет, то сделать белый список. А для доступа к любому сайту не из белого списка требовать пароль.

Вопрос: КАК это сделать? =))

Спасибо!

Comment: 1. Что за Zyxel? У них довольно разная продукция, в том числе и по возможностям...2. Рассматривается ли вариант [прокси][1] или [сетевого экрана][2]?  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD

Comment: 1. NBG334W EE.2. Я прочитал вики, но не особо понял...Сетевой экран настраивается непосредственно на компе? Если так, то этот вариант не подходит.Я правильно понял, что в случае с прокси сервером я должен подключить свой роутер к удаленному прокси, на котором уже есть сетевой экран? Если так, мне кажется, это то, что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Если на роутере есть родительский контроль, настраивай как хочешь...

Answer (score 1):

Или поставить старенькую машинку в разрез (между сетью и роутером), на ней уже воткнуть прокси или экран... Кстати, в этом девайсе есть [Фильтрация на основе содержания](http://zyxel.ru/sites/default/download/NBG334W/user_guide/nbg334w_ee_ug.pdf), может и поможет... в районе 110-ой страницы.